# How can I create a multiline split inside of a radical inside of an array environment?

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, align

I have an align like this:

```
\begin{align*}
\sigma &= \sqrt{\sum_x \left[ (x-\mu_x)^2\mathbf{f}(x) \right] } = \sqrt{\frac{1}{10}\sum_x (x-\mu_x)^2 } \\
 &= \sqrt{\frac{1}{10}(
    (0-.45)^2 + (1-.45)^2 + (2-.45)^2 + (3-.45)^2 + (4-.45)^2 +
     (5-.45)^2 + (6-.45)^2 + (7-.45)^2 + (8-.45)^2 + (9-.45)^2 } \\
 &= \sqrt{24.6525}
\end{align*}
```

However, this goes off the edge of the page. I wanted to create a multiline inside the middle square root symbol, so I tried this:

```
\begin{align*}
\sigma &= \sqrt{\sum_x \left[ (x-\mu_x)^2\mathbf{f}(x) \right] } = \sqrt{\frac{1}{10}\sum_x (x-\mu_x)^2 } \\
 &= \sqrt{\frac{1}{10}(
    \begin{split} (0-.45)^2 + (1-.45)^2 + (2-.45)^2 + (3-.45)^2 + (4-.45)^2 + \\
     (5-.45)^2 + (6-.45)^2 + (7-.45)^2 + (8-.45)^2 + (9-.45)^2 } \end{split} \\
 &= \sqrt{24.6525}
\end{align*}
```

but this gives me errors about mismatched curly braces.

Ideally, I would have something exactly like `\frac`, except which did not draw the horizontal line between it's operands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
\sqrt{\frac{1}{10}
\begin{aligned}
  ( & (0-.45)^2 + (1-.45)^2 + (2-.45)^2 + (3-.45)^2 + (4-.45)^2 +\\
   & (5-.45)^2 + (6-.45)^2 + (7-.45)^2 + (8-.45)^2 + (9-.45)^2 ) 
\end{aligned}
}
```

This works just like `align` but is only usable inside math mode.

There's also `gathered` which works like `gather`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much :)