# Splitting an equation with a long square root

Tags: equations, split, sqrt

I want to split up a very long equation. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,onecolumn,article]{memoir}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\text{RBE}(LET_d,D,(\alpha /\beta)_{phot}) = \frac{1}{2D}\cdot
\left(\sqrt{\left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right)_{phot}^2+4D\left(\frac{\alpha}
{\beta}\right)_{phot}\left(p_0+\frac{p_1}{(\alpha/\beta)_{phot}}\cdot
LET_D\right)+4D^2\left(p_2+p_3\sqrt{\left(frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right)_{phot}}
\cdot LET_d\right)^2}
-\left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right)_{phot}\right)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

And it looks like this:
[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! There are two approaches (a) introduce symbols for subexpressions (b) use building blocks such as `aligned` from the `amsmath` package that you already load.

Comment: ,@moriambar -- I don't think the duplicate you raised is relevant here because the real problem in the current question is how to split a long square root.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3330

Answer (score 1):

Making use of the `multline` environment and exploiting the repetition of some big terms; the shortcut `$\lambda=(\alpha/\beta)_{phot}$` can be used replacing `\lambda` with a suitable symbol if it is already used, one can do the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,onecolumn,article]{memoir} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\LET}{\ensuremath{\operatorname{LET}}}
\begin{multline}
\text{RBE}(\LET_d,D,\lambda) = \frac{1}{2D}\times{} \\  
\left(\sqrt{\lambda^2+4D\lambda\left(p_0+\frac{p_l}{\lambda}\cdot\LET_d\right)+4D^2\left(p_2+p_3\sqrt{\lambda}\cdot\LET_d\right)^2}-\lambda\right)
\end{multline}
%
where $\lambda=(\alpha/\beta)_{phot}$

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Another possibility (less readable, though) is to use `()^1/2` notation for the square root:

```
\newcommand{\ab}{\ensuremath{\Bigl(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\Bigr)_\text{phot}}}
\begin{align}
\text{RBE}(\LET_d,D,(\alpha/\beta)_\text{phot}) 
   &= \frac{1}{2D}\biggl[\biggl(\ab^2+4D\ab\Bigl(p_0+\frac{p_l}{(\alpha/\beta)_\text{phot}}\LET_d\Bigr) \notag \\                                                  
   &\quad+4D^2\Bigl(p_2+p_3\sqrt{\ab}\LET_d\Bigr)^2\biggr)^\frac12-\ab\biggr]
\end{align}
```

> [image]

Comment: You should really use `\textit{phot}` to get better spacing, though the difference is barely visible in this particular case.

Comment: @IanThompsom shouldn't it be upright instead. It is likely to be short for photon or similar, written in italics might get it confused with variable subscripts