# Array surrounded by a square root

Tags: math-mode, arrays

I would like to reproduce the following "cheat sheet" on a Latex document, but I can't figure out how to wrap the array around a square root symbol and place the values on top. [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3330/how-can-i-create-a-multiline-split-inside-of-a-radical-inside-of-an-array-enviro)
proved useful but I still can't get the desired result.

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: So what do you have so far? Please provide a Minimal Working Example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First the whole is drawn as array with place for the root symbol. Then, the root symbol is drawn on top of it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  \sbox0{$
    \begin{array}[b]{@{\kern.25em}ccccc@{}}
      0 & \frac{\pi}{6} & \frac{\pi}{4} & \frac{\pi}{3} & \frac{\pi}{2}
      \\[2ex]
      \llap{\rlap{$\sin$}\kern3.25em}0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
      \llap{\rlap{$\cos$}\kern3.25em}4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
    \end{array}
  $}
  \sbox2{$
    \sqrt{
      \def\x#1{\vphantom{#1}\hphantom{\frac{\pi}{6}}}
      \def\y#1{\phantom{#1}}
      \begin{array}[b]{@{\kern.25em}ccccc@{}}
        \y0 & \x1 & \x2 & \x3 & \x4 \\
        \y4 & \x3 & \x2 & \x1 & \x0 \\
      \end{array}
    }
  $}
  \kern\dimexpr
    3.25em -.25em -\wd2 + \wd0
  \relax
  \dfrac{\usebox2\llap{\usebox0}}{2}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]